For $G$ a graph, vertices $x_i$, $0 \leq i \leq n-1$; $(x,y)$ are connected by an edge if $x^3 + y^3 \equiv 1 \pmod n$. The graph is not connected.
Let $G$ be a graph of $n \geq 4$ vertices, labelled $0 \leq i \leq n-1$, where two vertices $(x,y)$ are connected by an edge if $$x^3 + y^3 \equiv 1 \pmod n$$
Show that the graph is disconnected.
Attempt:
The problem seems simple, but I'm having a real hard time solving it. Here are some disjointed paths I went down in my attempt. First, some sample pairs
For $n = 4$, the edges are :
$\{(0, 1), (1, 2)\}$
For $n = 5$, the edges are :
$\{(0, 1), (2, 2), (3, 4)\}$
For $n = 6$, the edges are :
$\{(0, 1), (2, 5), (3, 4)\}$
I thought maybe $x$ and $y$ can't both be even, but this is false for $n=5$ with $(2, 2)$, it also shows that $x$ can equal $y$.
I tried using a sum of cubes formula to rewrite the equation as $x^3 \equiv 1 - y^3 \equiv (1-y)(1+y+y^2) \pmod n$ but this didn't make it any clearer to me.
Also $x^3 + y^3 \equiv (x+y) (x^2 -xy + y^2) \pmod n$.
I tried thinking about a minimum number of edges for connected-ness, $n-1$, but see no reason why there must be less than $n-1$ edges, although experimentally above there is less than $n-1$.
I was thinking looking at pairs where one element is co-prime to the modulus, and the other is not, and couldn't see much of a pattern there either.
Any hints/insights much appreciated. I'm out of ideas.

In your problem statement, the vertices are numbered $1 \leq i \leq n$ but in your explorations you seem to be using a vertex number $0$. Can you clean this up?

Assume that $G$ is connected. Then there is a path between any two vertices. In particular, there is a path between 0 and any $0<m<n$. Follow the chain of congruences.

@RandyMarsh I posted an answer based on your suggestion which is hopefully somewhat correct.

As an attempt to answer my own question based on the comment by Randy Marsh, suppose by contradiction that there exists a path from $0$ to $n-1$. I wish to examine all simple paths leading outward from $0$.
Any edge that contains zero must be paired with some $y$ such that $y^3 \equiv 1 \pmod n$, where since $n \geq 4$, $1 \not\equiv -1 \pmod n$.
Then for any $z$ that shares an edge with $y$, it must be that $z^3 \equiv 0 \pmod n$. Continuing this reasoning, for any simple path leaving from $0$, it must have values $\pmod n$ of $(0, 1, 0, 1, 0...)$, and hence cannot ever lead to $n-1$, and so $G$ is not connected.

I'm not sure I understand the conclusion - why should it be that the path (mod $n$) from 0 to $n-1$ should end in a $-1$?

It should end in $-1 \pmod n \equiv n-1 \pmod n$. Is this what you had in mind, or a different argument?
